# Linux tool/method to copy thousands small files and directories

Tags: linux, shell, filesystems, copy

What can I do to improve the speed to copy thousands small files and hundreds directories, summed to 19 GB as this's too slow:

```
cp -ap /a /b
```

I'm using Linux

Comment: If you plan ahead and make `a` a subvolume in Btrfs then you can "copy" inside the same filesystem instantly by making a snapshot. And I believe you can copy to another Btrfs with `btrfs-send` (although not as easily, I think).

Answer (score 1):

Keep your expectations low. With small files there's a lot of filesystem overhead and it will take a while to copy all of them.

Sometimes the `tar` hack can make it a bit more efficient:

```
cd /sourceDir
tar c . | (cd /destDir; tar x)
```

Comment: Good practice: `cd … && tar …`. Alternatively `tar -C …`.